# How to debug/breakpoint Sub Main()?

Tags: vb.net, debugging, program-entry-point, breakpoints

I am debugging someone else's software and it doesn't look like the code within `Sub Main()` is getting hit.

How can I check that the code in main() is actually running?

**Main():**

```
Sub Main()
        ‘some code
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you sure that you are using the "Debug" configuration  and not the "Release" one?

Comment: `Sub Main` is debuggable. Are you sure that your `Main` sub is called? You can output something to check it or check in the properties of your project what the Startup Object is.

Comment: Yes, I am in debug mode. Then in that case it is actually not being called. Where in the project properties can I see the startup object? I am only able to see the startup project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments, first get sure that you have set `Sub Main` as the startup object.
To do this:

1. Right click on your project
2. Select Properties
3. On the left panel select the first item `Application`
4. On the right panel you see a dropbox with the label `Startup
   objects:`
5. Select `Sub Main`

After that your `Sub Main` will be called and should be also debuggable.